# How to return primary keys generated from a COPY FROM statement in postgreSQL?

Tags: c#, python, postgresql, return, primary-key

I'm uploading thousands of rows into my postgreSQL database and to do so I'm using the `COPY FROM` statement to save processing time.

I didn't found any information about that on StackExchange so I'm asking now: is it possible to retrieve the primary keys (or other column value) generated from the COPY statement like we could do with the `RETURNING col_name` statement of an `INSERT` statement ?

Comment: Copy into a TEMP table; then do a `insert into real_table (...) select ... from temp_table ... returning *`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible with `COPY`.

Only an `INSERT` with `RETURNING id` can give you id-s.

The fastest next to `COPY` approach would be a multi-row insert:

```
INSERT INTO table(col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2), (val3, val4),... RETURNING id
```

Comment: Ok that is what I tought. I can't do a multiple insert because I need the speed gain the COPY FROM gives me comparing to multiple inserts.

Comment: @kaycee the example I gave you isn't for multiple inserts, it is for a single multi-row insert, which makes a huge difference, and it is very fast.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant sorry. But as it says here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/populate.html, "Note that loading a large number of rows using COPY is almost always faster than using INSERT, even if PREPARE is used and multiple insertions are batched into a single transaction." That is why I want to use COPY.

Comment: `almost` leaves a lot of room for speculation :) And if your dataset fits into a single multi-row insert, like 10,000 rows or less, then multi-row insert would be even faster. Also, you asked how to get id-s, and this is the only way.